# carregar conteúdo depois de um elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando fazer uma função para carregar um conteúdo com `.load()` do `jQuery`, o `.load()` recebe um parâmetro `param` que seria o endereço do arquivo.
E gostaria que esse `html` fosse carregado após um elemento especifico, no caso `aside`.
Tentei utilizando o método `.after()` mas não consegui, gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma solução?!

E tenho outra dúvida, após carregar esse conteúdo novo, se os métodos que estão dentro do `$(document).ready();` ainda irão funcionar, para interagir com os novos elementos carregados?!

**Linha HTML onde está o evento onclick**

```
<li class="list-group-item pointer" onclick="getTemplate('admin/email/lista-emails.php')">
  Lista de E-mails
  <span class="indicador success white right">14</span>
</li>
```

---

**Código Javascript**

```
function getTemplate(string){
  $("#here").after().load(string);
}
```

Obs: Ele carregou o conteúdo dentro do **aside**

Comment: Qual erro é apresentado no console?

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de informar... Ele carregou o conteúdo dentro do aside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
function getTemplate(string){
  $.ajax({
    type     : 'GET',
    url      : string,
    dataType : 'html',
    success  : function(data){
      //remove o conteudo caso já tenha carregado
      //e evita carregar multiplas vezes o mesmo conteudo
      $("#loadContent").remove(); 
      //carrega o html após o elemento ASIDE que resultou na consulta.
      $('aside').after(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu, marque com o V verdinho ao lado dela (mesmo que seja essa sua mesmo) para marcar como resolvido, em vez de editar o titulo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) para buscar o conteúdo e [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) para posicioná-lo, ao invés de load() e after();

```js
function getTemplate(string){
  var html = $.get( string );
  $( html ).insertAfter('#here');
}
```

Comment: Consegui trazer atraves de uma chamada ajax, que fiz, mas ao utilizar esse método que `insertAfter`, ele me retornou esse erro: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined`

Comment: quando vc chama `$.get( string )` ele tem que retornar um html bem formatado, senão pode dar esse erro

Comment: E como eu iria pegar esse html do objeto retornado e inserir após o `#here`, ele traz o html no `responseText`

Answer (score 0):

Poderia ser feito utilizando done do $.getJSON();

Assim:

```
funtion getTemplate(parametro){
  $.getJSON("url", data : {paramentronome : paramento }).
   .done(function (dado ) {
      $("#div").html(dado);
   });
}
```

Isso ajuda?

Comment: Vlw mas atraves de suas respostas montei uma chamada ajax, agora falta inserir o conteudo depois da tag `#here`

Comment: A sua tag #here, você quer adicionar o conteudo nela? É isso, eu não entendi direito o que seria essa tag e o que seria feito com ela ...
Se for para adicionar o conteudo nela seria 
`$("#here").html("texto"); // adiciona um html novo`
`$("#here").append("texto"); // adiciona um texto ao que ja existia`

Comment: Vlw já consegui resolver, queria carregar o conteudo depois da tag.